# Can BizTalk HL7 Accelerator produce HL7 v2XML compliant messages

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, hl7, btahl7

By default, it looks like the HL7 accelerator produces XML from HL7 v2 messages which is not HL7.org compliant (doesn't match their XML v2 XML schemas).  Is it possible to get it to generate HL7 v2XML compliant xml?

**Edit:**
We have xslt transforms that transform HL7v2 XML into other xml formats.  These are used by other tools that are part of our platform.  We would be able to simply re-use these transforms in BizTalk if the BTAHL72XRecievePipeline component generated HL72 compliant XML, but for some reason the xml produced by the pipeline is slightly different.  I am unsure why that is.

If you look at the standard HL7 2 XML specs from HL7.org the element names use periods instead of the underscores that the biztalk schemas use, and the element names in the biztalk schemas are appended with the name of the field/component, whereas in the HL7.org schemas the field/component names are specified as optional attributes on the element.

It appears that the BTAHL72XReceive/Send piplines require the BTAHL7 schemas while the BTAHL72XMLRecieve/Send piplines use the HL7 2 XML schemas.  But wouldn't it make sense to be able to use HL7 2 XML from the BTAHL72XReceive/Send piplines as well?

Answer (score 0):

This [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee404918.aspx) walks you through getting the adapter to work with the HL7 v2 XML schemas. There is also a link on that page to a tool that does the work. Oh, and here is another [supporting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb981217%28v=bts.10%29.aspx) article.

Comment: I've looked at that article, but that doesn't seem to be what I'm after.  See edit on original question...